# Backwards compatibility of onBackPressed

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

If I use onBackPressed() on Android 1.5, my application crashes. Is there any possibility to deactivate this function if running on an Android 1.5 device?

The code there is not absolute necessary but a real "nice to have", so I would like to keep it on newer devices and just drop it on older ones.

Is this possible?

edit: I think I found it, just the old way:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
       // do something on back.
       return true;
   }

return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: That's indeed the way to go for older handsets ;) Looks like the code i use at least :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to detect runtime which version of SDK using your application and depending on that prepare different branches. Like:

```
@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
{ 
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT==Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE) //if it's 1.5
    {
       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) 
       {        // do something on back.        
          return true;    
       }  
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
}
```